# Get specific data for on-demand Crystal Report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I need a hyperlink to my main Crystal Report to call another drilled-down report based on that specific (clicked) row.

Right now I've managed it using on-demand sub-report facility of crystal report. But this requires entire data (thousands of rows) for both the reports. Then CR will filter data for the sub-report at run-time. I'm getting these data by calling a service which returns me data as JSON string. So it might cause a heavy network traffic.

Here's what I need actually. Is there a way to get back to the server with a value from clicked row, and then call the second report with the filtered data for that row only ?

I'm using SAP Crystal Reports version 13.0.15.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

when you click a row pass that value through `sub report links` to the sub report from main report.

In sub report use that in `record selection formula` so that only required records are retrived.